# Adjust the layout when the Android soft keyboard is shown or hidden

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview, android-softkeyboard

My goal is to achieve what most messaging apps like Facebook messenger, Viber, What's up do when displaying an attachment sheet. If the Soft keyboard is visible and the user wants to attach something, the keyboard is hidden and the attachment sheet is presented in its place.

In order to make this work, the layout changes should happen when the root view size changes. Otherwise, a graphical **glitch** occurs where my layout changes are applied shortly before keyboard is shown/hidden.

If I could change my layout the exact moment the keyboard is hidden, I could get it right. I have tried using `onGlobalLayoutListener` but without the desired outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to find out whether your layout changed due to the keyboard (dis)appearing and acting on the change is inside `onMeasure()` of the root layout.

In more detail, I made a custom LinearLayout, which is used as my root layout. I overrided the `onMeasure` and I [calculate](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/2114024ab1d9cf209916bcdb3a4a7d44e51a3b0c/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/Components/SizeNotifierFrameLayout.java#L65) what is the current keyboard height. Depending on the keyboard's height and whether my attachment grid should be visible or not, I change the visibility of the attachment grid. I can even set the grid's height the same as the keyboard.

The results looks like the grid was always beneath the keyboard and the textview remains in the same vertical place.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the manifest of your activity.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.your.Activity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

Comment: This doesn't help. I **want** the keyboard to change the layout, but when it gets hidden I want to be able to keep the layout in its previous position so that the attachment view is displayed. I can't figure out how all these apps get this behavior.

Comment: try this   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustNothing"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code It will be Helpful.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: I want the layout to change when the keyboard is presented. I want to able to replace the keyboard with the attachment view when the keyboard is dismissed.